# Jquery how to add :hover to css style sheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is the CSS I like to convert to jQuery code:

```
BUTTON:hover .buttonTextDIV {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border-right: 4px solid #d1dbea;
border-bottom: 2px solid #d1dbea;}
```

I use a filter in 4.01 Transitional and I have a problem with the $().hover event where the effects of the filter are negated by the onmouseleave function which $().hover uses to "emulate" the css :hover option when it leaves the object.

So I need to "hardcode" button:hover .buttonTextDIV using jQuery.

I want to specifically add this to each element seperate using : $(".buttontext").each(function(){}

Is there a way to do this?

I don't want people telling me not to use 4.01, if you intend on doing that please move on to the next question.

Comment: what's the reason to do this directly from jQuery? can't you just use the above css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript cannot directly define or edit pseudo classes of CSS. Not unless you edit the CSS directly. But if `hover()` is not working for you (you didn't indicate why?), I can only suggest that you try manually defining your own events:

[.mouseenter()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)
  [.mouseleave()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)

[.mouseover()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)
  [.mouseout()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/)